# Why does the synchronization between multiple processes of variables in shared memory linux go wrong?

Tags: linux, synchronization, shared-memory, memory-barriers, thread-synchronization

I create a shared memory used to share data between processes. The shared memory saves data using a data structure:

```
struct shared_cfg {
    volatile uint32_t idx;
    volatile uint32_t cfg_lock;
    ...
};
```

In my program:

- different processes should get an unique value of "idx" every time.
- after process P1 modified the viraible "idx", process P2 is expected to use the new value of "idx" and update it.
- Then P1 will get the new value that saved by P2.
- ...

But I found that when the concurrency increases, P2 occasionally read the old value of "idx", which means P1 and P2 got the same value of idx:

```
typedef volatile uint32_t lock_t

void lock_idx(lock_t *lock)
{
    uint32_t old_lock = 0;
    do {
        old_lock = __sync_val_compare_and_swap(lock, 0, 1);
        if (old_lock == 1)
            usleep(10*1000);
        else
            break;
    } while (old_lock == 1);
}
void unlock(lock_t *lock)
{
    __sync_lock_test_and_set(lock, 0);
}

idx = 0;
```

**P1:**

```
lock_idx(&cfg_lock);
idx = idx + 1;
unlock_idx(&cfg_lock);
```

**P2**

```
lock_idx(&cfg_lock);
idx = idx + 1;
unlock_idx(&cfg_lock);
```

I insert memory barrier by API "*mm**fence" before and after the modification of "idx", but the problem still exist:

```
idx = 0;
```

**P1:**

```
lock_idx(&cfg_lock);
_mm_mfence()
idx = idx + 1
_mm_mfence()
unlock_idx(&cfg_lock);
```

**P2:**

```
lock_idx(&cfg_lock);
_mm_mfence()
idx = idx + 1
_mm_mfence()
unlock_idx(&cfg_lock);
```

The error log is like this:

```
P1: get lock 
P1: idx is 1; update idx to 2 
P1: unlock

P2: get lock 
P2: idx is 2; update idx to 3 
P2: unlock 

... 
P1: get lock 
P1: idx is 63; update idx to 64 
P1: unlock

P2: get lock 
P2: idx is 63; update idx to 64 
P2: unlock 
...
```

How to share variables between multiple processes by shared memory?

Comment: Barriers don't create atomicity, neither does `volatile`.  That's what `std::atomic<int>` is for.  (Or C11 `atomic_int`.)

Comment: The initial version of the question didn't mention anything about locking!  Assuming that lock works, I notice your later critical sections code blocks don't include reading the old `idx` into a local variable.  If you only read `idx` separately after an atomic increment, of course you'll sometimes get duplicates.  That's what GCC `__atomic_fetch_add` (or the obsolete `__sync_fetch_and_add`) are for, or C11 `atomic_fetch_add`

Comment: `__sync` builtins are already full barriers, as strong as `_mm_mfence()`.  Your lock looks correct, I think, if you're calling it correctly.  It's weird to use `__sync_lock_test_and_set(&lock, 0)` to unlock, but it should work as well as `__sync_lock_release` which is just a release-store, unlike other `__sync` functions.  i.e. it's like `atomic_store_explicit(&lock, 0, memory_order_release)`.

Comment: Anyway, this isn't a [mcve] of what you're doing.  You aren't showing the code that captures the old and new values of `idx`, just critical sections that increment without capturing either old or new value.  Like `fetch_add` without using the return value.

Comment: Thank you. I replaced "idx = idx + 1" with __async_fetch_and_add, and it works!